# Why does Wordpress Editor Only Use Half the Box?

Tags: themes, child-theme

Whilst editing a WordPress website I got asked to update, I stumbled upon this problem.

Text wrapping.

When editing the text on one of the pages, I realized that the text stops mid-page and goes onto the next. Now, I have tried numerous suggestions by people on certain sites and still have the same problem. I do not have access to the cPanel, just the Wordpress backend, so these suggestions were limited.

I can access the Appearance-Editor, but I really need help on what to change in the codes, please.

I am using a child theme of a Twentyforteeen template, by the way. I just need to know how to edit it, so that I can make a particular page utilize all sections of it.

Please help.

[image: see example here]

Comment: Themes can add an editor stylesheet that would set a max width on the text. The reason it would do this is to match the appearance on the front end. I'd wager your theme is capping the line length at the same size it appears on the front and, so that they're 1:1.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I think so, too. Please how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it's because of the theme. Does your theme did this before or did this happened after you tweaked something.

If you tweaked something out of curiosity, backup your `*.css` files and put a new one via [FTP](https://filezilla-project.org/) or via your file manager.

There are numerous protocols for reaching your Cpanel. Try the following:

1. `YourIPaddress/cpanel` eg. `http://85.13.219.117/cpanel`
2. Or the easiest is type `YourDomain.com:2083`. If that didn't work, try `YourDomain.com:2082`

> Take note to replace **YourDomain.com** with your domain or IP address.

Go to your your `public_html` on your server or via `cpanel > file manager` or look for any files that end with and replace it with a fresh one. You can find one on other themes.

But if your not sure of what you're doing, simply go to `../public_html/wp-content/themes` and rename the folder on which theme you're using. After that go to your Wordpress admin and reinstall the theme.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I have no access to the cPanel.

Comment: @Dude did you tried my suggestions? Do you have your login infos?
If that, then you have to access your files via sftp.

Comment: What about using other theme?

Comment: Oh no sadly, I can neither use another theme nor access the cPanel. Is there a way I could modify it from Editor

Comment: You can modify it on the editor but I won't recommend that. If the theme is alright before and only shows that after a random tweaking, try uninstalling the theme and installing, activating it again.